# Non-greedy regular expression to convert command tags

Tags: unix, vim, regex, sed

## Background

Consider the following text:

```
There are three types of font families: serif, sans serif, and
teletype.  To switch between these families, use <cmd>rm</cmd> for
serif, <cmd>ss</cmd> for sans serif, and <cmd>tt</cmd> for teletype.
```

I would like to change `<cmd>x</cmd>` to `{{cmd|x}}`, as follows:

```
There are three types of font families: serif, sans serif, and
teletype.  To switch between these families, use {{cmd|rm}} for
serif, {{cmd|ss}} for sans serif, and {{cmd|tt}} for teletype.
```

## Problem

The regular expression for non-greedy matches is tricky. For example, the following does not work in vim:

```
:%s/<cmd>\(.*\)<\/cmd>.\{-}/{{cmd|\1}}/
```

Nor does the following, with sed:

```
sed -e "/(<cmd>\(.*\)</cmd>).\{-}/{{cmd|\1}}/"
```

The parenthesis try to match parenthesis, rather than group the expression to apply the non-greedy operator of either `\{-}` or `?`. Escaping the parenthesis is used for backreferences, which is only required for the text content inside the `<cmd>` tag.

## Question

What is the correct syntax to non-greedily replace all occurrences of `<cmd>x</cmd>` with `{{cmd|x}}` in a file?

Note: This is not an attempt to parse HTML using regex. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried this in VIM: `%s/<cmd>\(.\{-}\)<\/cmd>/{{cmd|\1}}/g`, and it converts your demo text to:

```
There are three types of font families: serif, sans serif, and
teletype.  To switch between these families, use {{cmd|rm}} for
serif, {{cmd|ss}} for sans serif, and {{cmd|tt}} for teletype.
```

It seems like your first regular expression in VIM is really close to solve your puzzle, but the usage of `.\{-}` is not in the correct place.

I get the hint from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy-in-vim